# Clash of methods when implementing Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

**spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.2.RELEASE**

I'm trying to access the dababase like in this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/#_create_simple_queries

This is my repository:

```
package ru.pcask.clients.repositories;
import ru.pcask.clients.entities.Client;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Long> {
    Client findById(Long id);
}
```

And the error:

```
'findById(Long)' in 'ru.pcask.clients.repositories.ClientRepository' clashes with 'findById(ID)' in 'org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository'; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

But I get errors like in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Just remove that method, it is already part of the `CrudRepository`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your return type. As mentioned above, the method `findById(Long id)` is already implemented in the `CrudReposistory<T, ID>` and it returns an `Optional<T>`.

You can either remove the method in your code because it is already there or override it with the correct return type `Optional<Client>`.

Comment: Is the tuturial wrong?
Why did they wrote: Customer findById(long id);   ?

Comment: The `Optional<T>` data type was introduced with Java 8. Then, it might have lasted a while until it was integrated in the `CrudRepository<T, ID>`. The tutorial might have been created before the introduction of this data type and they did not update the tutorial...